# repository not found ros on ubuntu 21.04

Tags: ubuntu, ros, gazebo-simu

I am trying to install [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu) on ubuntu 21.04 but this error is shown to me when I run `sudo apt update` on the terminal. Also, I tried to use the Mirror repo but the same error is shown to me.

```
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ROS release for 21.04. The latest distro is [Noetic](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic) which targets 20.04. You'll either need to downgrade or try to install it in some 20.04 container(i.e. docker)